# I want to add class directly into color picker input box

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';
      
<SketchPicker color={this.props.color} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

[image]

I want to add a class in the input element directly.

Comment: Have you tried passing a CssClass name on Render like `return <SketchPicker className="my-class />`

Comment: yes, but work for me. I want to directly added class in input element @Helio

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking but it seems that you want to add CSS styling directly to the internal input of the react component. The quickest way to do this (although not the cleanest) is to override the css.

You can add styles directly to the id of the input:

```
#rc-editiable-input-61 {

     ...css rules here

}
```

Or you could use css combinators:

```
.name_of_unique_parent_class input {

   ...css rules here

}
```

There is not enough information in your screenshot to give you a detailed explanation, but there are many online resources on combinators and css overloading.

[Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators)
[Overriding CSS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-override-the-css-properties-of-a-class-using-another-css-class/#:%7E:text=Like%20Article-,To%20override%20the%20CSS%20properties%20of%20a%20class%20using%20another,other%20element%20has%20higher%20specificity.)